# Tensorflow: Train Keras model using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I know, there are a lot of related questions, but they are outdated, mostly they are even dealing with TensorFlow 1.

I have 1 GPU (GeForce 960) which is recognized by TensorFlow, so the installation was successful.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but this is how I train a Keras-model:

```
def create_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding="valid"))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(layers.Activation(activations.relu))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
  return model

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0"])

with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["acc"])

train_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()

model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=20,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=test_dataset)
```

But I get a lot of problems:

1. The exact same code is equally fast when I turn off the Strategy part
2. I always get this "warning": `BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence`
3. I found out, that when I run this code, with the strategy part turned off, in a different Anaconda environment which does not have GPU support (CUDA etc), then it is way slowlier. So, is the GPU automatically used when you are in a GPU supporting environment (because, as stated in 1., it is equally fast without the strategy part)?
4. Is this the right way to use my GPU? If not, what is the right way?

Comment: yes, the GPU is automatically used if supported and available, there is no need for the strategy

Comment: But when I train in colab using TPU, I do need a strategy. So that's a different thing, right? And is there a way to check if the GPU is used?

Comment: TPU training is quite different from a GPU training. For the GPU, at the beginning of the task tensorflow should prompt something like : _Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with **** MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: *****, pci bus id: ****)_ and you should see all the CUDA, CuDNN libraries opening. You can also use the command _watch nvidia-smi_ to check your GPU usage (if you're on Nvidia obviously).